# Carousel for old Angular version (1.0.5)

Tags: angularjs

I have a rather large web application that runs on angular 1.0.5 (yes I know it prehistoric).

I want to add a slider/carousel just like this: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/carousel

However it's not really compatible to my version of angular, as far as I can see.

Suggestions to another carousel are welcome. Requirements

- Start over (when end og the slide deck is reached -> start from the beginning )
- Swiping (must work on ios)
- Preferably light weight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try an older version of `angular-ui/bootstrap`: [Tag `0.4.0`](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/releases/tag/0.4.0) is build on AngularJS `1.0.5`.

Comment: Tried that but could for some reason not get it working - but thanks for the suggestion

Comment: After another go I got it working. However, no touch support :-(

Comment: `ngMobile` was introduced with `1.1.5` and renamed to `ngTouch` as of `1.2.0` - so, nope, there was no build-in touch support as of `1.0.5`.